# Ways to track login/loading progress dynamic?

Tags: unity, c++, java, software-engineering, design-patterns

Lets say we want to add a dynamic "loading bar" to our server-client game... the player presses on "login", a bar appears and shows the percentage of loaded assets and configurations from the server.

The only way i found... is very laborious and hardcoded :

```
// We received our environment
barPercentage += 10f; // Increasing the bar.
updateBar();

// We received our player settings
barPercentage += 5f; // Increasing the bar again
updateBar();
```

As you can see this progress tracking from received server data is very bad and needs to be adjusted everytime you change some important part of the game structure itself.

What are good ways to implement such a percentage tracker client side ? How do we actually track the loading progress (client & server related) without hardcoding it like i did in the code sample ? Are there any good patterns or data structures ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be for the server to enumerate the content it needs to send at the time the download is initiated, and start by sending the player an estimate of the total download size.

Ie. "User A is logging in, in game state B. That means I need to send them map X and assets Y and Z. Altogether that makes ## MB of data, so I'll tell them to expect that much"

Now on your client side, you can tabulate how many bytes of data you've finished receiving so far, divided by the total the server told you to expect, to figure out your progress through the total load, without knowing at compile time what files / roles might be included in that set.

If you have additional stuff that might add time — like unpacking/parsing/initializing assets after they've been received, or allowance for extra dependencies that are only identified later in your load process, you can add an extra fudge factor to your initial estimate, and then gradually decrease that fudge factor as these extra uncertainties are resolved.